# Why word boundary is not working in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

Why this one works with regularexpressions(re) module in python.

```
import re
x = 'if a + b > 0 && a - b < 0:'
print(re.search(r"\s&&\s", x))

output:<re.Match object; span=(12, 16), match=' && '>
```

And this one not?

```
import re
x = 'if a + b > 0 && a - b < 0:'
print(re.search(r"\b&&\b", x))

output:None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word boundary assertions (`\b`) describe a transition between word and non-word characters, not between space and non-space characters. Word characters are alphanumeric characters plus the underscore (`_`). But since both space and `&` are non-word characters, `\b` can't match at that transition; you'd only match if the `&` had a word-like neighbor, when you thought you were looking for a non-word-like neighbor.

Comment: x = 'this is a word'
print(re.search(r"\bis\b", x))